# Le mot pour le type de plat

Tags: expressions, alimentation, noms-collectifs

Si on a une collection de recettes, de types 'entrée', 'apéritif', 'plat', 'dessert' etc etc, qu'est-ce que c'est le nom collectif pour ces choses? (si il existe)

C'est pour les catégories des recettes dans un site web Wordpress.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas bien la question.  Entrées, desserts... sont des types de plats. Le mot collectif qui est recherché est-il pour un ensemble de plats tous du même type (desserts, légumes, viandes, entrées, etc.) ou un ensemble de recettes regroupant tous les genres ? Peut-être que de regarder un site de recettes français pourra aider. Par exemple, [celui-ci](http://www.marmiton.org/).

Comment: En fait, il faudrait qu'on sache ce qui va être présenté. Sur un site de recettes de cuisine, en général, soit on a directement au 1er niveau du menu, les différents types de recettes "apéritifs", "entrées", "plats"... Soit un 1er niveau avec différents choix + le choix "recettes", et au 2ème niveau du menu les types de recettes.

Comment: Pour précision : je parle du menu de navigation du site web (ou barre de navigation) dans mon commentaire précédent et non du menu composé de différents types de plats.

Comment: @laure Au bord, j'ai choisi Type de Recette exactement comme vous direz, le 1er niveau c'est les 'apéritifs, plats, préserves etc', alors ce sont les types de recette, ainsi je les ai étiqueté comme ça. 
Merci beaucoup. (anche @Izzi)

Comment: "préserves", tu veux dire conserves ? (English preserves)

Comment: conserves - oui, merci ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I would say **Plat**.

According to [Larousse.fr](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/plat/61521?q=plat%20plate#150523) :

> Élément d'un repas : Un menu à trois plats.

Comment: Oui: plat principal = *main course*

Comment: It is also possible to say " service " as in " Menu en X services "

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a pas de mot spécifique pour regrouper les différentes catégories: entrée, plat principal, dessert, hors-d'oeuvre...

La plupart des sites de cuisine en français regroupent ces catégories dans une rubrique qu'ils nomment **Recettes**.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer given here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/le-mot-pour-le-type-de-plat/27447#27447) (i.e., *plat*) would probably be my first choice, primarily because it could easily apply to and include dishes that, although surely benefiting highly from skilled “presentation,” do not require “preparation” per se immediately prior to serving (such as plates of cheese or crudities).

However, in light of the fact that your question already includes *plat*, in both its title and its body, perhaps you were hoping to find something else and if that is the case, you might consider

> ***[un/les] mets*** (invariably written with an “s”),

which according to its entry in my trusty hard copy of *LE ROBERT-MICRO* means:

> Chacun des aliments qui entrent dans un repas.

Although the above definition of *mets* doesn’t seem to require/include the notion of “preparation,” my previously stated main reason for preferring "plat" and, more importantly, my resulting implied preference to hesitate using/proposing words that might imply the notion of "preparation," stems from the inclusion of the “preparation-required” notion of *apprêté* in the following [*Larousse.fr* entry for the word](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mets/51045?q=mets#50937) (with emphasis added):

> Tout aliment **apprêté** qu'on sert aux repas.

[This *n-gram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plats+et+boissons%2Cmets+et+boissons%2Cnos+mets%2Cnos+plats&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplats%20et%20boissons%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmets%20et%20boissons%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnos%20mets%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnos%20plats%3B%2Cc0) could arguably be evidence that *plat* is indeed a better answer than *mets* (and as I go to post this, I’ve just noticed that you’ve wisely accepted it), for it shows that when prefaced by “Nos …” (which many restaurants do when heading a list/collection of their different [categories/types of] menu offerings), *plat* has been used slightly more often than *mets* (but see the opposite result when the two are combined with “*et boissons*”).
 Nevertheless, in spite of *n-grams*' (and my own) preference for "Nos plats," “Nos mets” is also sometimes used by restaurateurs for this seemingly relevant purpose, as shown on [this link](http://www.newbisse.ch/nos-mets/nos-mets) to the website of *Le New-Bisse*, a pizzeria-pub located near the town of Granois (Savièse) in Switzerland.

Comment: *Mets* is a collective noun for dishes, but not for courses.

Comment: @Gilles Mets-en! J'ai bien raté mon coup!

Answer (score -1):

It's usually "Menu".
• "Apéritif" is the time people can spend drinking and nibbling before the meal
• "Entrée" (in the French sense) is the first meal

Comment: *Menu* can mean a series of courses. One course isn't a menu.